# catkin_create_package TypeError

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to create a simple catkin package, but I'm getting a strange error that I could not find an answer on the forum or google. This is what I get:

```
ariel@ariel-GT70:~/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_create_pkg test roscpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 61, in main
    newfiles={})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 209, in create_package_files
    _safe_write_files(newfiles, target_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 185, in _safe_write_files
    fhand.write(content)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Any ideas?.
Thanks for the answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218835/catkin_create_package-typeerror/) by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2015-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-10-08**:
Please post the platform you are using.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2015-10-09**:
I'm working on ubuntu 14.04 (64 bits) with ros indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you have this installed in `/usr/local`, perhaps via pip. Do you also have a version installed in `/usr` via apt-get install?

If so, remove the pip version and use the Debian package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2015-10-08**:
I've never used pip. To be sure I removed and purge ros* and re-installed (ros-indigo-desktop-full) it and I still have the same issue.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-08**:
You mean it's still running out of `/usr/local`?

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2015-10-08**:
Yes, in /usr/local. This is what I have:

ls /usr/local/bin/
catkin_create_pkg      catkin_make_isolated    catkin_topological_order
catkin_find            catkin_package_version  easy_install
catkin_init_workspace  catkin_prepare_release  easy_install-3.4
catkin_make            catkin_test_results

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-09**:
The Debian packages do not install to /usr/local, so you have some other version there, which you need to delete from both /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2015-10-12**:
I believe I should NOT do rm catkin*, right? What would be the best (and safest) way to remove everything from /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages?

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2015-10-12**:
I did rm catkin* in /usr/local/bin and the issue was solved. Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-12**:
If you did not use pip, `rm` was probably the only solution. Please click on the check mark if it answered your question.